# Calculating coefficients of a quadratic fit inside GMSH geo script

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, mesh

I have faced a problem which requires calculating the coefficients of a matrix to be used in Gmsh .geo file. I have created a small script using Matlab to solve a 2x2 matrix. The code is as follows;

```
clear all;clc;close all 
R = 0.509515; % m
R1 = 0.559467; % m
R2 = 0.579594; % m
L = 0;
L1 = -0.08568;
L2 = 0.13974;
y = [R1-R;R2-R];
x = [L1^2 L1;L2^2 L2];
c = x\y;
x1 = linspace(-0.08568,0.13974,20);
```

From the above small code, I need to use the coefficients in matrix `c`, which I transfer as `c1` and `c2` manually to the following geo file

```
R = 0.509515; //% m
R11 = 0.10; //% m
R1 = 0.559467; //% m
R2 = 0.579594; //% m
L = 0;
L1 = -0.08568; 
L2 = 0.13974;
c1 = 4.811;
c2 = -0.1708; 

nPoints = 20; // Number of discretization points (top-right point of the inlet region)
For i In {1 : nPoints}
  x = L1 + (L2-L1)*i/(nPoints + 1);
  pList[i] = newp;
  Point(pList[i]) = {x,
                ( c1*x^2+c2*x+R ),
                0};
EndFor
Spline(1) = {20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

Note that in the geo file, I am not able to use `linspace` because I don't know if `linspace` syntax exists in GMSH. My aim is to make the geo file solve the matrix to fit the quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is just to solve a 2 x 2 system of linear equations right inside GMSH.

By adding the following calculation instead of directly inserting values of `c1` and `c2` will move the work from Matlab to GMSH. Note, since it is a 2 x 2 system, I did not take the numerical stability into account; however, for such a small system for a practical application, it should not be important anyway.

```
// Calculating solution of Ax=y
// A = [L1^2 L1; L2^2 L2]; y = [R1-R; R2-R]; x = [c1;c2]
// Ainv = 1/det(A)*[L2 -L1; -L2^2 L1^2]
// x = Ainv*y
det = L1*L1*L2-L1*L2*L2;
If (Abs(det) < 1E-10) //Yeah, I am lazy.
    Printf("Ill-conditioned fit required. Will crash.");
EndIf
factor = 1./det;
c1 = factor*(L2*(R1-R) - L1*(R2-R));
c2 = factor*(-L2*L2*(R1-R) +L1*L1*(R2-R));
```